# Cant use browser.send_keys("{tab}") in Watir- Load Error

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am not able to identify Rich TextBox using Watir. So I tried to use `browser.send_keys(“{tab}”)` to press tab. But that produces an error. I tried uninstalling `ffi-1.0.10-x86-mingw32.gem` and installing ffi –v 1.0.9 but that doesn’t work. I am getting an error like this:

```
irb(main):013:0> browser.send_keys("{tab}")
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi_c
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.10-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.10-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/window.rb:67:in `const_get'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/window.rb:67:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:456:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:456:in `rautomation'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/ie-class.rb:475:in `send_keys'
        from (irb):13
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):014:0>
```

I use Watir 3.0.0,
Ruby 1.9.3.

Gems:

- bigdecimal (1.1.0)
- builder (3.0.0)
- commonwatir (3.0.0)
- ffi (1.0.10 x86-mingw32)
- hoe (3.0.6)
- io-console (0.3)
- json (1.5.4)
- minitest (2.5.1)
- nokogiri (1.5.3 x86-mingw32)
- rake (0.9.2.2)
- rautomation (0.7.2)
- rdoc (3.9.4)
- rubygems-update (1.8.24)
- s4t-utils (1.0.4)
- user-choices (1.1.6.1)
- watir (3.0.0, 1.5.3)
- watir-classic (3.0.0)
- win32-api (1.4.8)
- win32-process (0.6.5)
- windows-api (0.4.1)
- windows-pr (1.2.1)
- xml-simple (1.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
browser.send_keys :tab
```

I believe Watir 3.0 changed the send_keys method to be like that in Watir-Webdriver - see http://watirmelon.com/tag/send_keys/

Comment: Hi Justin, I have already tried it and I'm still getting the same error. Anything else I can do???

Comment: Did you try the newer versions of ffi?

Comment: Justin that worked fine. I installed ffi-1.0.12.rc3-x86-mingw32.gem and it works. Awesome!!! but is there any way to find a hidden text area using Watir Script???

Comment: Yes, hidden fields can be found by doing browser.hidden(:id, 'id'), or any other standard locator. It has the standard .set and .text methods. (Note you should start new questions as new questions.)